# JS script to automatically import files without input button

Tags: javascript, html, csv, filereader

I have a table on my website and I'd like its data to be imported from a local CSV file. I did researches and found [this awesome CSV parser](https://www.papaparse.com/) with the function `Papa.parse(file, config)`. In this function, the attribute "file" has to be imported locally with `<input type="file" />` but I couldn't find anyway this "file" to be imported automatically on the  page load.

Is there anyway to do it or am I obliged to do it with an input ?

Comment: on page onload function write a script to automatically click the button.

Comment: Browser is client and hence cant directly import or read the file from local machine where browser is running. You are obliged to do it with an input type file only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a deliberate security restriction to stop malicious web pages from attempting to steal data from a user's machine without their knowledge or permission. The browser can only read files the user explicitly gives to it via an `<input type=file` control.  There is no way to bypass this.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, I'll try the script that automatically clicks the button.